# Update a textbox dynamically when a PHP table is updating.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, textbox

In PHP codeigniter, I have an interface to add sales records. I select the item and quantity and enter it to the table below.

At the bottom there is a textbox to hold the total price. So I need to update the text box when I'm adding records to the table. how to do it?

Comment: Can you  show your code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Family. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) good question

Comment: what about if you use ajax??

Comment: Actually the code is too long to add here. Im getting information from a Database table and add it to the table in the interface. Then i need to set the summation of a one column in that table into a text box dynamically

Comment: I didnt use ajax . Is there any example relevant to this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do this directly from php try using jquery/javacript

**Procedure to do it from jquery**

In a way that when ever value of the input field is changed call a function which will re calculate the sum of all the fields again

Say you have a table in html like

```
|id|Name       |Price|
----------------------
|1 |Some name  |10   |
|2 |Some name  |20   |
|3 |Some name  |30   |
|4 |Some name  |40   |
----------------------
|  |           |100  |
```

and and input field some where in a form. 
`Id` of that input field = `"priceInputField"` and `Class` of each column containing price = `"priceValue"` and Id of the column containing the total is `"totalPrice"`
so your jquery function would look like

```
$("#priceInputField").on("change",function(){
    //Some code to add the new row in the table
    var updatedPrice = 0;
    $(".priceValue").each(function(){
        updatedPrice = updatedPrice + $(this).text;
    })
    $("#totalPrice").text("updatedPrice");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't update things dynamically as you type. You would have to submit the form, then in PHP you calculate the total, and return the result on a new page. If you want to update the total as changes are being made without having to submit the form and wait for a new page to load, you will need to use Javascript.

Comment: @Caugau Thank you for your answer. Is there a known script for a this kind of a situation? please help since im new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asynchronous javascript (AJAX) for dynamic changes in table or page. Please see **Ajax & PHP Powered MySQL Table Editor / Viewer / Data Grids**

http://www.webhostingreviewslist.com/development/top-10-ajax-php-powered-mysql-table-editor-viewer-data-grids/?wb48617274=255F1A36

Answer (score 0):

you can use

ajax  -> update database return success

appendTo ....   show new record

->call function cal price